# how to do periodic migration from database to database using mapforce

Tags: c#, sql, map-force

I need help in migrating data from legacy database to the new database using MapForce. (Both databases are in MSSQL)

I am a student and I have pretty good knowledge of databases but bad at other languages.

**Scenario**

I have a CUSTOMER table in legacy database (We are still using legacy system) and a CLIENT table the new database (Which we need to populate before going live with new system)

I have already mapped fields between these two tables in MapForce and I have generated C# script.

**Question**

What to do next ? to make it work and migrate data from Database-1 to Database-2 between those tables?

How to do it periodically or only few records at t time so it won't affect the performance?

Will it also pick up the changes once the records are copied across ?

**What I want to Achieve**

I want to copy records from the "CUSTOMER" table from legacy system to the "CLIENT" Table in new system.

I also want the MapForce to re-copy them again if there are any changes in legacy records.

Comment: The biggest compication here is recognsinsing changes in the source records. You need something that records a change was made in the source record and something that recognises the record has been sent. This is called differential replication. Does your C# script for example have any code to connect to either database? What happens when you compile your C# ? It looks like MapForce is for XLST transformations, not database migrations.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input.  C# have generated the code to connect tot the databases. I was thinking that MapForce is the application that allows to migrate data between databases.

Comment: So what happens when you compile your code? Is it a console application? Anyway I'm sure there must be loads of doco online to help. I just typed in Mapforce data migration and there were heaps of sites.

Comment: Yeah.. It compiles and does what it supposed to do but now i don't know how to make it recognise any changes

Comment: If you want differential replication that implies both systems are live. Is that correct? Normally you would have a migration strategy that involves migrating all data then turning off the old system (with a few test runs), OR, both systems are live at the same time.

Comment: Yes, legacy is live and the new system is in testing. We want to populate it before going live and also some of the staff may still use legacy system fore few months after going live with new system

Comment: There's some thinking to do here. Differential replication is a certain amount of effort. Do they want to bear that cost because some staff _might_ use the legacy system?. It introduces a lot of confusion, for example when a change is made in both systems but then the legacy system overwrites the live system afterwards. Also you could simply refresh _all_ clients (i.e .do an update on everything) or if there is a 'date last changed' in the source system you could just update all records changed in the last week. This is probably all outside MapForce though. I've never used it though.